# Having trouble interacting with wep pages using Selenium in Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use the HtmlUnitDriver and WebElement classes of Selenium in Java to click the "Download as CSV" button on Google trends.

The problem I'm having is that that button is hidden (not displayed) until you click a different settings menu button, but I can't click that settings menu button with WebElement.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * @args String, the term to search on Google Trends
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //instantiate an HtmlUnitDriver
    HtmlUnitDriver hud = new HtmlUnitDriver();

    //navigate to the 90-day Google Trends page of the input term in args
    hud.get("https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=" + args[0] + "&date=today%203-m&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT%2B8");

    //set element to the first button to press
    WebElement element = hud.findElement(By.id("settings-menu-button"));

    //click the element
    element.click();
}
```

The error I am getting is: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: You may only interact with visible elements

But the settings menu button is visible?

This is my first time making a program like this and using this library, so thanks for any help. I'm still learning.

Comment: javascriptexecutor is not possible here to click on that element?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //instantiate an HtmlUnitDriver
    HtmlUnitDriver hud = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(hud , 120);
    //navigate to the 90-day Google Trends page of the input term in args
    hud.get("https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=" + args[0] + "&date=today%203-m&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT%2B8");
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("settings-menu-button")).click();

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I'm still getting "You may only interact with visible elements ... "

Comment: can you try wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("settings-menu-button")).click();

Comment: Now it is just waiting forever, indicating that the element is never visible

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the real browser (e.g. Firefox, Chrome):

```
ChromeDriver hud = new ChromeDriver();
```

Reasons:

- https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver

> None of the popular browsers uses the javascript engine used by
>   HtmlUnit (Rhino). If you test javascript using HtmlUnit the results
>   may differ significantly from those browsers.

- https://gist.github.com/evandrix/3694955

> Headless browsers that have JavaScript support via an emulated DOM
>   generally have issues with some sites that use more advanced/obscure
>   browser features, or have functionality that has visual dependencies
>   (e.g. via CSS positions and so forth)